# What is an interval of a lattice?

Tags: definition, order-theory, lattice-orders

What is an *interval* of a lattice in order theory?

In the Wikipedia page of [modular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), there is a theorem that uses the notion of *interval* ([diamond isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice#Diamond_isomorphism_theorem)), but the term *interval* is not defined there and the definition is hard to find on Google because the search results are mostly about lattices of intervals.

Can someone provide the definition?

Comment: [Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of interval for partial orders is a subset $S\subseteq X$ such that, for all $x,y\in S$ and for all $z\in X$ such that $y\le z\le x$, $z\in S$.

There is a general notion of closed/open/half-open interval in, say, $[a,b]=\{x\in X\,:\, a\le x\le b\}$. Notice, however, that these are not necessarily intervals in the sense I've mentioned. The wikipedia page is referring to this kind of "interval".

Comment: For completeness, could you please add the definition of $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 4):

The answer given (and already accepted) gives what seems to be the definition of interval of a poset, according to its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Intervals) which is also linked to in a comment.

I was amazed that people call intervals to such subsets of posets;
as far as I am concern, a subset $C$ of a poset $P$ satisfying the property $p \in C$ whenever $a,b \in C$, $p \in P$ and $a\leq p \leq b$ is called a **convex** set.

This is the definition given in *Introduction to Lattices and Order*, by Davey and Priestley, page 63 (in the second edition) and also in *General Lattice Theory*, by Grätzer, page 21 (in the second edition too).

These references seem never to define formally what is an interval, but always refer to an interval as a closed interval, $[a,b]$, an open interval, $(a,b)$ or an half-open interval, $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$, where $a\leq b$.
(I think that Davey and Priestley only refer to closed intervals, but I'm not sure.)
Here,
$$(a,b) = \{x : a < x < b\},$$
$$(a,b] = \{x : a < x \leq b\},$$
$$[a,b) = \{x : a \leq x < b\},$$
while the closed interval is, of course, defined as in the other answer.

Apparently the definition is not standard.
See also the ProofWiki definitions of [Convex set](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convex_Set_(Order_Theory)) and [Interval](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Interval/Ordered_Set) (coincide with the ones I referred to).